# What was the first two-panel file manager for DOS?

Tags: history, ms-dos, utilities

I'm trying to settle a debate between me and some colleagues about two-panel file managers in MS-DOS/PC DOS.

According to my own recollection the first was DV.EXE (see *EDIT* below), but some of my colleagues are adamant that NC.EXE (Norton Commander) was the first.

Could be we are all wrong and there was another that preceded those.

Please note: We are looking for a proper DOS program. Not a CP/M program that could also work under DOS.

*EDIT:* I was able find the original license and box of DV in our company archive.
"**DV** The **D**ual**V**iew FileManager" (c) 1984 by Osmond Software Works Ltd.
The license was dated October 27 1984.
I tried finding out more about Osmond Software Works, but I'm drawing a blank there.

Comment: Mind to add a definition what a proper DOS program would be, considering that DOS 1.x was a CP/M clone for most parts? Beside that no CP/M program would work without being ported proper.

Comment: @Raffzahn I would say originally written and designed for DOS as opposed to a original CP/M program ported to DOS.

Comment: Ok - makes me wonder what quality that differentiation that brings. It seems arbitrary, doesn't it?

Comment: @Raffzahn Were do you draw the line? I guess any criterion I care to define will have some arbitrariness to it.

Comment: Hmm. I guess some criteria are less forcing and more 'natural'. For example, I would call any application that runs _native_ under MS-DOS (no emulation or translation layer used) a by and large proper.

Comment: @Raffzahn That is a good definition, I have to agree. But that doesn't take away that it may be a port anyway. (E.g. ping is available as a native command on just about any OS that has a TCP/IP stack, but they are all ports of the original BSD version.) And I wasn't looking for ports.

Comment: Not arguing here, just try to understand. Adding 'no port' while asking for a generic functionality works fine when one wants to get the first implementation, independent of any OS. But it's not a reversible function. When adding any not-first OS as restriction, it essentially means 'only clones please' , doesn't it? So what makes a program reimplemented from scratch (if there is such a thing at all) different form one that got ported?  (Sidepoint how do you know that all ping on all OS are ports?)

Answer (score 14):

I think that both [PathMinder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PathMinder) and Bourbaki’s 1dir predate your examples, but I don’t know if they are the first DOS-specific dual-pane file managers. PathMinder was first published in 1984, 1dir (pronounced “wonder”) [in 1983](https://books.google.fr/books?id=qURs4j9vKn4C&pg=PA596). 1dir didn’t always show two panes listing files; it only did so when copying files, and I’m not sure whether it did so in its initial versions.

Norton Commander was released in 1986; I don’t know when your other candidate was. (To me, `DV` is DESQview!)

[This history of DOS file managers](https://www.techrepublic.com/pictures/dinosaur-sightings-dos-file-managers/6/) shows the later 1dir+ in action, and [this page on Arthur-PC](http://www.arthur-ds.hu/arthur-pc_eng.php) shows the CP/M version of PathMinder with its dual-pane interface. (Note that PathMinder was initially written for DOS, and ported to CP/M later.)

Comment: I know all about the confusion between DV and DESQView. We had BOTH back in the early 90's and it was a never ending source of frustration for the people running the company helpdesk back then.

Comment: At least these both predate NC.exe (1986). I seem to recall DV.EXE was 1984 or 1985. I may be able to find the original license for DV we bought somewhere in the company archives, but due to Covid restrictions it may be weeks (or longer) before I will be able to get to the office in person.

Comment: > _…1dir (pronounced “wonder”)…_.  Oooooooh!

Comment: I found our original license for DV and the box with the original 5.25" floppy. In 2005 a colleague of mine cleared out the old software from the cupboard with all the originals in our office while I was on holiday. I always thought everything had gone into the skip, but apparently he put everything in a couple of large boxes and placed them in the archive. The box (manual is gone unfortunately) says (c) 1984 and the license is dated 27 October 1984. So it is probably a toss up between PathMinder and DV, depending who exactly is older. I will not consider 1dir as it isn't fully 2-panel.

Comment: Does the box give a less concise name than DV? Who was it published by? (Perhaps you could add the information to your question!) While I’m at it, any chance you could archive the floppy?

Comment: @StephenKitt Didn't think of that. I should have made a photo of the box. But I remember the salient details well enough. Will be 2 or 3 months before I get back to the office. I will edit it in the question for now and will correct if I later find I had it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The original XTree was released in early 1985 so predated Norton Commander, I believe.

I'm not *entirely* certain that this first version had split screen (dual panel) but I know my trusty copy of XTree Gold (or Pro, I can't really remember) did. That was released a couple of years *after* the original however.

Comment: I actually used XTree back in the day next to DV. And XTree didn't have the 2 panels as far as I can remember.